# Plotting second figure with matplotlib while first is still open

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

K here's a more precise example of what I am trying to do. I am using WXBuilder for Python as my user interface with multiple plotting functionality i.e. the user must be able to plot a graph based on their chosen parameters. After a graph is plotted I want the user to be able to plot a second without closing the first figure. This is for comparison purposes. Below is an oversimplified example of what I am looking to do.

```
import matplotlib as plt

def OnPlotClick1(self, event):  
        plt.plot(self.DateArray1, self.kVAArray2)
        plt.show()

def OnPlotClick2(self, event):        
        plt.plot(self.DateArray1, self.kVAArray2)
        plt.show()
```

Now I am assuming my problem is arising due plotting and showing() the graph, and therefore the program somehow is blocked from functionality until the first figure or plot window is closed.

I hope this explains my problem better.

Comment: Please show a [*minimal*, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code you're running for us to reproduce the problem, as obviously this is possible.

Answer (score 4):

You should not block show. Use:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3])   # first plot
plt.show(block=False)  # do not block
plt.plot([11,21,31])  # second plot
```

Answer (score 1):

Each window is in matplotlib parlance, a new figure. You can call `plt.subplots` twice to create two figures:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
y1 = np.sin(x)*np.exp(-x/5.0)
y2 = np.sin(x**2)*x
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(x, y1)

fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
ax2.plot(x, y2)

plt.show()
```

Note that `plt.show()` starts a GUI event loop and so generally it [should only be called once](http://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#use-show) per script.

Comment: Isn't that a little overkill? Wouldn't the OP have enough with `plt.ion()`?

Comment: @OliverW.: If you know how to do this with `plt.ion()` please post an answer.

Comment: @OliverW: You're right that multiprocessing is overkill though; two figures suffice.

Comment: Indeed, I hope you didn't get me wrong. Your solution *is good*. But I wasn't sure what the OP meant by "keeps crashing" so thought I'd wait.

Answer (score 0):

You can also draw 2 or more than 2 plotters in the same figure

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def my_plotter(ax, data1, data2, param_dict):
    out = ax.plot(data1, data2, **param_dict)
    return out
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
#here you put your data
data1=[0,1,2,3,8]
data2=[0,1,2,3,8]
data3=[0,1,2,3,8]
data4=[0,1,2,3,8]

my_plotter(ax1, data1, data2, {'marker':'x'})
my_plotter(ax2, data3, data4, {'marker':'o'})
plt.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can either follow @(Corrupted MyStack) suggestion or with interactive graphic devide. Run

```
plt.ion()
```

once, anytime before you start the plots. To turn it off

```
plt.ioff()
```